# How to get location in Android within a service

Tags: android, service, gps, locationlistener

I want to start a service which will run in the background, and will show latitude and longitude every 30 to 45 seconds.
Below is my code which I'm using:

```
public class LocalService extends Service implements LocationListener {
    private final static String TAG = "LocalService";
    LocationManager lm;


    public LocalService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        subscribeToLocationUpdates();
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        Log.d(TAG, loc.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), loc.getLatitude() + " - " + loc.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("Location", loc.getLatitude() + " - " + loc.getLongitude());
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
    }

    public void subscribeToLocationUpdates() {
        this.lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        this.lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30, 0, this);
    }
}
```

I'm calling my service like this:

```
startService(new Intent(TimerServiceActivity.this,
         LocalService.class));
```

This is my manifest code for service:

```
<service android:name="LocalService" >
```

Whenever I am running this code it gives me an error message that unfortunately, `TimerService` has stopped.

Comment: What does the LogCat (stack trace) say?

Comment: post stacktrace (-1 for complaining about a crash without a stacktrace)

Comment: Use https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll

Comment: Please keep in mind that this will drain the battery.

Comment: @A--C , njzk2 i am not getting any error but warning and its not stopping.

Comment: @Zohaib when it says `TimerService has stopped.` and TimerService is your app name it means it's a full crash.

Comment: Copy paste all the red message in your logcat, there definitely must be a stack trace

Comment: @A--C . i forgot to add permissions thats y it stopped . not app is working but i cant get location in Toast

Comment: @SalGad there are no red messages . only orange.. may be eclipse is not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the permissions added in your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I instead highly recommend using this library optimized for battery usage and is rather simple to use:

http://code.google.com/p/little-fluffy-location-library/

> Based on the concepts in, and some code adapted from,
>   android-protips-location by Reto Meier, from his blog post A Deep Dive
>   Into Location.

Comment: i have added permission.. but i cant get any toast giving me location

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe to a provider first. To do this, add this in the beginning of your onCreate() method:

```
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    Log.v(TAG, "Init");
    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
```